# Java Iterator<Integer>: unable to cast next() to Integer

Tags: java

I have a problem with Iterator. If I call in Iterator object the next() method, then I cannot cast the returned value to Integer. Do you know why? If I call iterator.next().getClass().getName(), it returns this very strange String: "[I".
Thank you for reply!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with the question and show us the code snippet of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you by any chance calling `Arrays.asList(someIntArray).iterator().next()`, where `someIntArray` is an `int[]`?

Comment: _[I_ is the JVM type signature for an array of `int`, in other words `int[]`. Maybe you can post the relevant part of your code, including how you obtain your iterator?

Comment: I think you could use `IntStream.of(yourIntArray).iterator()`.

Comment: @Michal your question has been put on hold because there is no [mcve] demonstrating the problem. You should add one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[I` is the JVM representation of `int[]`.

You don't have an `Iterator<Integer>`, you have an `Iterator<int[]>` (or, more generally, an `Iterator<? super int[]>`).

This typically happens when you try something like:

```
int[] someIntArray = {1,2,3};
Iterator<int[]> iterator = Arrays.asList(someIntArray).iterator();
```

because `Arrays.asList`, as a generic method, will only accept reference typed arguments: `int` isn't a reference type, but `int[]` is, so `Arrays.asList(someIntArray)` is a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>` as is perhaps intended.

Comment: Yes! That was my case! Thank you a lot! So next time I have to create Integer[] and not int[] array, haven't I?

Comment: @MichalDouša that is one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Andy! Or by for loop...